# Pass large parameters to browser

Tags: api, crystal-reports

I created more than 20 reports using crystal report. Now I am integrating them to my API service. One particular report uses the following parameters:

```
lngCompanyId=1
szITSfromCompany=Sample
strGroupBy=Region
strGroupBy1=Greater Accra
strQuery1='and #tblRetOutletSumm.iRegionID=4'
strQuery2='and #tblRetOutletSumm.iDistrictID=8'
strQuery3='2016-10-27'
strQuery4='2016-10-27'
strPicHeight=1
strPicWeight=1
```

Now i have to pass them to my web browser to generate the report. I tried the following URL after running the project:

```
http://localhost:20010/Home/CreateSummaryReport?lngCompanyId=1&szITSfromPersol=Sample&strGroupBy=Region&strGroupBy1=Greater Accra&strQuery1=and #tblRetOutletSumm.iRegionID=4&strQuery2=and #tblRetOutletSumm.iDistrictID=8&strQuery3=2016-10-27&strQuery4=2016-10-27&strPicHeight=1&strPicWeight=1
```

It broke the code. It passed up to `strGroupBy1` which is `Greater Accra` but when it came to `strQuery1`, it only showed me the first word which is `and` instead of `and #tblRetOutletSumm.iRegionID=4` and all the remaining parameters threw `null` values.

I know the '#' tag causes the problem, so how do I pass the parameter? Or should I change a the database procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the **'# tag'** by **ascii symbol** solved the issue.
I changed the **'#' tag** by **'%23'** and the issue is solved.

Somad